# Reshape DataFrame (long form data) to a "summary" DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, group-by, dataframe, reshape

All, I am new to python.  I am trying to automate reshaping I typically perform in excel as follows

```
#Import long form data from CSV into pandas data frame
In 1: Data = [My Long Form DataFrame imported from a CSV file]

City        Population
Chicago     1,245
Los Angeles 2,457
New York    998
Chicago     1,854
New York    1,654
Los Angeles 2,478
Los Angeles 760
more...

#Reshape "Data" DataFrame to a summary DataFrame "DataByCity"
In 2: DataByCity = pandas.DataFrame(Data.reset_index().groupby(['City'])['City'].count(), columns = ['Count_Cities'])

Out 2: 
City        Count_Cities
Chicago      5
New York    10
Los Angeles  8
```

Next (need help here), I need to add on more columns from "Data" to "DataByCity".  For example, I need sum the populations by city from "Data" into a list and append that list to "DataByCity".

```
In 3: ??????
Out 3: 
City     Count_Cities  Sum_Pop
Chicago      5         10,128
New York    10         18,457
Los Angeles  8         16,950
```

Finally, I need to add a calculated fourth column to "DataByCity" (['Sum_Pop'] / ['Count_Cities'])

```
In 4: ???
Out 4: 
City     Count_Cities  Sum_Pop  Avg_Pop
Chicago      5         10,128   2,025.6
New York    10         18,457   1,845.7
Los Angeles  8         16,950   2,118.75
```

Appreciate any help!  I have searched these forums for days, as well as python documentation.  I just can't put the clues together.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will find what you want described here: [Applying multiple functions at once](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once)

Start with Data as your dataframe, with both City and Population as columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

grouped = Data.groupby('City')

df = grouped['Population'].agg({'Count_Cities' : np.count,
                                'Sum_Pop' : np.sum,
                                'Avg_Pop' : np.mean})
```

Alternatively you could work with the pivot tables feature.

The answer to your final question you will find [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#column-selection-addition-deletion) without any trouble.